# Ansible failing to SSH with password instead of Key

Tags: ansible

I am using ansible to try and set up a server. At the moment the server has a root user who authenticates with a password (no ssh key required). If I ssh manually from my command line I am prompted for the password and log in no problem.

This is what I'm seeing when I try and use ansible:

```
python3 $(which ansible) our.server.net -m ping -c ssh --ask-pass -u root
SSH password: 
our.server.net | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "SSH Error: data could not be sent to remote host \"10.123.80.75\". Make sure this host can be reached over ssh",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

If I add -vvvv I get a bit more info (just including the important bit here)

```
Loading callback plugin minimal of type stdout, v2.0 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/minimal.py
META: ran handlers
Using module file /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/modules/system/ping.py
<10.123.80.75> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<10.123.80.75> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d9 ssh -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey -o ForwardAgent=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o User=root -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/martinw/.ansible/cp/eeb0630cdf 10.123.80.75 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/bin/python && sleep 0'"'"''our.server.net | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "SSH Error: data could not be sent to remote host \"10.123.80.75\". Make sure this host can be reached over ssh",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

Is there something I'm missing in my environment / ansible settings here?

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Jeff Geerling](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/), has answered this problem.

https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2018/fixing-unreachable-ssh-error-when-running-ansible-playbooks-against-ubuntu-1804-or-1604

https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2017/how-fix-ssh-errors-when-using-ansible-newer-oses-ubuntu-1604

> It's easy enough to work around this problem, though! If you have the ability to build your own base images (e.g. AMIs on AWS), you can just make sure /usr/bin/python is already installed on the image. And if only python3 is present, you can set `ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3` in your inventory for the affected hosts. If you can't do either of these things, the best

Or install working python version.

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  pre_tasks:
    - name: Install Python if not already present.
      raw: test -e /usr/bin/python || (apt -y update && apt install -y python-minimal)
      changed_when: False

    - name: Gather facts after Python is definitely present.
      setup:
```

Comment: There is a bug logged to improve the error reporting on this https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/28870